# Firebase on Android Doesn't Persist Data?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Currently using Firebase v3. I am trying to save the Firebase User's display name once the user logs in.

So far, I have the following snipet of code:

```
FirebaseUser fbUser = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
if (fbUser != null) {
    // User is logged in
    Log.i("Task User", fbUser.getUid());

    DatabaseReference userRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users").child(fbUser.getUid());
    userRef.child("display_name").setValue(fbUser.getDisplayName())
      .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            Log.i("Task Complete", task.toString());
            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Log.e("Task Fail", e.toString());
        }
    }).addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
            Log.i("Task Success", "Success");
        }
    });
}
```

My Firebase rules are set such that only authenticated users and read or write:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

I can verify that:

- the user is successfully authenticated
- `Task User`, `Task Success`, and `Task Complete` are logged in output
- there is bandwidth registering on the Firebase Realtime Database usage page

[image: Realtime usage]

However, everytime I look at the Realtime Database page, I still see `myapp: null`. Is there anything obvious I am missing?

Comment: Please share you json tree

Comment: `udiaapp: null` (It's the empty tree, I haven't been able to programmatically add any data through the Android Firebase api)

Comment: kindly share your complete json tree, i will help you with it

Comment: I figured it out. `fbUser.getDisplayName()` returns `null`. I added a check to ensure that there is always a value there.